# Android Widget with AlarmManager and Configuration

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I want a widget that have a configuration activity, which asks some information to user. Once the information is provided by user I want my widget to be updated every 10 minutes. So I need an Alarm Manager. On every 10 minutes my widget fetches some data from my website and displays it on widget, for that I can use service.

From many days I am trying to implement this. I googled a lot, but failed while putting all these together. I can implement alarm manager separately, I can implement services separately, I can use configuration activity separately. But when I put all these in a single project I get lots of error.

Can anyone please refer me any document or example that may help me?
Regards,
Bhavin Mistry.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the service part but here is a widget with AlarmManager and Configuration Activity:

http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/take-your-time-widgets-and-alarmmanager/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use AlaramManager to implement timer. I tried its working fine for me in sleep mode also check [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/) for more details also this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html) may help you.